# Samsung Washer turns itself ON

Tags: washer

My samsung washer has started  (4 time over 5 days now) turning itself ON.  Yes ON.  No lights on front panel but it sounds like it is draining water although it is empty.  When I open the door, it continues.  When I push power on the front panels lights up and it stops.  Help!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement.Sounds like a problem with the controller board, or perhaps some external power problems.